# The Signed Applet on Java 6

Tags: java, security, applet, cross-compiling, signed-applet

My Java signed applet which is signed by Netbeans works well on Java's which is version 7.
But on version 6 it does not work. How can I solve this problem.Is Java version 6 does not allow this? This is HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<applet archive="mi.jar" code="Mi.class" witdh="500" height="500">MY APLET</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You use Java 7 and want to run on Java 6, try option of compiler to generate compatible bytecode

Comment: thank you for answer.how can i do that on netbeans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java compiler `javac` has an option to compile the code to generate compatible bytecode for other platform versions by specifying `-target` option. Consult the cross-platform option in Oracle docs for [Cross-Compilation Options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html). If he code compiles with this option then you could run both platform if not then you have to rewrite the Java 7 code to be compilable for the Java 6 platform.

In the Netbeans IDE there should be a project settings where you could change either JDK or language level.